# performance governor isn't honoring settings

Tags: performance, cpu, governor

I have followed posts on askubuntu.com trying to figure out why my Xeon E3-1231 won't go more than 800MHz (I've disabled Turbo from BIOS)

Governor is set to performance

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

lscpu says (I'm pasting only partial output)-

```
CPU MHz:             798.187
CPU max MHz:         3400.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

cpufreq-info says-

```
analyzing CPU 7:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 7
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 3.40 GHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 798 MHz.
```

Turbo seems to be disabled-

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

i7z says-

```
  TURBO DISABLED on 4 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
  Max Frequency without considering Turbo 3392.00 MHz (99.76 x [34])
  Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  38x/38x/37x/36x
  Real Current Frequency 798.06 MHz [99.76 x 8.00] (Max of below)
  Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %   C7 %  Temp      VCore
  Core 1 [0]:       797.94 (8.00x)           1    58.3       1       0    40.6    25      0.7094
  Core 2 [1]:       797.88 (8.00x)           1    23.6       0       0    76.4    21      0.7114
  Core 3 [2]:       797.90 (8.00x)           1    29.8       0       0    70.2    24      0.7103
  Core 4 [3]:       798.06 (8.00x)           1    21.7       0       0    78.3    23      0.7148
```

When I run `stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1024M --timeout 20s`

then `i7z says`-

```
  TURBO DISABLED on 4 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
  Max Frequency without considering Turbo 3392.00 MHz (99.76 x [34])
  Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  38x/38x/37x/36x
  Real Current Frequency 797.88 MHz [99.76 x 8.00] (Max of below)
        Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %   C7 %  Temp      VCore
        Core 1 [0]:       797.88 (8.00x)         100    76.5       0       0       0    24      0.7094
        Core 2 [1]:       797.88 (8.00x)         100    76.5       0       0       0    24      0.7065
        Core 3 [2]:       797.88 (8.00x)         100    76.5       0       0       0    26      0.7103
        Core 4 [3]:       797.88 (8.00x)         100    76.5       0       0       0    24      0.7148
```

Ubuntu version-

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I'm quite confused given that cpufreq-info says that `frequency should be within 3.40 GHz and 3.40 GHz` but it still stays at 800MHz anyway.
Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Does frequency scaling work properly if turbo is enabled in the BIOS? Does this processor have HWP (Hardware P-State control)? If yes, does frequency scaling work properly with it disabled? Does frequency scaling work properly when using the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver (i.e. boot with intel_pstate disabled)? Under heavy CPU what do you get for `sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:8 -d -a 0x198` (requires msr-tools package), and `sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:8 -d -a 0x199`? (p-states given and p-states asked for.)

Comment: Perhaps edit your question adding the information listed by turbostat (linux-tools-common package) when it starts without the --quiet flag set. In, particular is the PROCHOT bit set? If yes, it would force the lowest CPU frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @DougSmythies . While I was waiting for answers the day before, I reached out to the datacenter for help as well. They tried troubleshooting, in vain, and ended up replacing the CPU from E3-1231 to E5-2643 and it is working properly. Guess I'll never know what was wrong.